# How to get ansible to stay on the machine after finishing a task?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to run a task which starts up build engines. Once they have all started, ansible returns control to me and I see that they all stop at once. When I add an async: 10 flag to the running of the script it works, but the problem is when there are multiple build engines it takes longer than 10 seconds for them to start, which makes the async kind of null.

I have tried using a

```
- pause:
  seconds: 10
```

task below the running of the script, but the build engines stop, then it does the pause.

What I am asking is - Is there a way to make ansible stick around on the machine for a few seconds after it has finished running the command (i.e. after control has been returned to user)?

Comment: Rather than launching build engines as children of itself, you should use the ansible `service` module or similar to get `init` to launch long-running processes on your behalf. Then the jobs will run until you use ansible to stop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried wait_for but that seems to exit the environment and then perform the task.
I fixed this problem by using the following in my shell execution task:

```
async: 300
poll: 5
```

This runs the task asynchronously and polls every 5 seconds for a response.

Answer (score 0):

While it's unclear what kind of build system you are using and why it can't properly daemonize itself, i think [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_module.html) module is perfectly suited for your needs. You can wait for tcp port to come up, if your build system opens one, wait for some file to be created, parse log files for string, indicating that build has started successfully or simply wait for some time.